# Specifying the `stratum` and `alluvium` parameters without attaching ggalluvial

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `ggalluvial` with `ggplot2`, though, I'd like to be able to generate the same plot without attaching `ggalluvial` but only specify its use with `ggalluvial::`. If it is not attached, I get the following error: `Error: Can't find stat called "stratum"`.

```
d <- data.frame(

    status = rep(c("state1","state2","state3"), rep(90, times=3)),
    cellIndex = rep(seq_len(90), times=3),
    cellCategory = c(rep(letters[seq_len(3)], each=30),
                     rep(letters[c(2,3,1)], each=30), 
                     rep(letters[c(3,1,2)], each=30))
)


ggplot2::ggplot(data=d, ggplot2::aes(x=status, stratum=cellCategory, alluvium=cellIndex,
                fill=cellCategory, label=cellCategory)) +

    ggalluvial::geom_flow(stat="alluvium", lode.guidance="rightleft", color="darkgray") +

    ggalluvial::geom_stratum() +

    ggplot2::geom_text(stat="stratum", size=3)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a tough one---digging into the [code for ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/layer.r), the stat argument pastes the string you give and then looks for that object (in this case "StatStratum") in the environment you're in. Because you don't want to load the package, it won't be able to find it (and there's no way to change the argument itself).

#### Answer

So you need to save that object from the ggalluvial package like so:

```
StatStratum <- ggalluvial::StatStratum
```

Then leave the rest of your code as is.

Comment: Sorry for commenting after a couple of years, but is there any update to this? I try your answer but I keep getting `Can't find stat called stratum`

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

```
ggplot2::geom_text(stat = ggalluvial::StatStratum)
```